# how to find the prediction cut off point in r

Tags: r, prediction

I am training a glm model where my class attribute 'adverse_effects' is a factor containing 0 and 1

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

model_logreg <- train(adverse_effects ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=trainSplit_logreg, method = "glm", trControl = ctrl)


predictors <- names(trainSplit_logreg)[names(trainSplit_logreg) != 'adverse_effects']
pred_logreg <- predict(model_logreg$finalModel, testSplit_logreg[,predictors])
```

This is the summary of predictions

```
summary(pred_logreg)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-14.5600  -2.1220  -1.8700  -1.9890  -1.7090  -0.9459
```

How do I know the cut off point of prediction? How can I map the results of the prediction back to 0s and 1s?

P.S I got an auc of  0.6144

Answer (score 0):

`predict.glm` takes a `type` argument which determines the scale on which to make predictions. I think you want `type="response"`, so try

```
predict(model_logreg$finalModel, testSplit_logreg[,predictors], type="response")
```

The natural cutoff is 0.5, which would select the most likely outcome. Unless you have a special situation (e.g. false negative worse than false positive) I would stick  with 0.5 as a cutoff.